# Why isn't "\400" a compile-time error?

Tags: java, string, unicode, unicode-string, string-literals

Character values between 0 and 255 can be denoted by octal literals from `"\000"` to `"\377"`.

So shouldn't `"\400"` be a compile-time error? Eclipse does not complain, however... what's going on here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's interpreting it as "\40" + "0"

The Java Language Specification describes this [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#101089).

```
OctalEscape:
    \ OctalDigit
    \ OctalDigit OctalDigit
    \ ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit

OctalDigit: one of
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

ZeroToThree: one of
    0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Personally, I think it would be better if it failed. It's an awfully cryptic distinction.

Answer (score 5):

It falls under the construction of

```
\ OctalDigit OctalDigit
```

... followed by '0'. It *doesn't* fall under

```
\ ZeroToThree OctalDigit OctalDigit
```

... so it's not ambiguous or out of range. See [section 3.10.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#101089) of the Java Language Specification for more details.

Note that you can't use it as a *character* literal for exactly this reason:

```
char x = '\377'; // Fine
char y = '\400'; // Error: unclosed character literal
```

Comment: If the "unclosed character literal" error message is from the official javac, it would fit nicely in a list of strange error messages.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I don't think it's that strange. It's not restricted to this situation either: `'abc'` would do it too.